# Is it possible to host a TCP endpoint in an IIS6 hosted service?

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I created a wcf service based on ServiceHostFactory, and i'm hosting it in IIS6.
If i use a HTTP endpoint everything works just fine, but when i try to switch to TCP it goes bad.

Is it even possible to do this in II6?

I have a more specific question posted here, that asks for a solution, but i would be happy with (for starters if not) with just an answer (and perhaps an example) to this - less specific question.

[Why can't I connect to a WCF service with net.tcp but i can with http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201004/why-cant-i-connect-to-a-wcf-service-with-nettcp-but-i-can-with-http)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIS 5.1 and IIS 6 can only host HTTP bindings.  IIS7 has WAS (Windows Activation Service) which allows hosting of endpoints bound to any transport protocol... so it would be capable of TCP.

If you must host with IIS 6, then you're stuck with the HTTP bindings.  If not, consider self-hosting in a Windows Service.